# How do I update a combo box on an MS-Access form when the value of another combo box on that form is modified?

Tags: ms-access

I am developing an MS-Access application.  The database contains an Activity table that has two fields to identify the location where the Activity occurred:  StateID and CityID.  Both fields are foreign keys to other tables (State and City).  The City table has a foreign key to the State table, pointing to the State that contains that City.

I have an Activity form based on the Activity table.  The form contains two combo boxes, one for StateID and one for CityID.  I would like the user to select either the State or a City where the Activity occurred.  If user just selects a State without specifying a city, no problem.  However, if the user selects a City, I would like to update the StateID field with the State where that City is located.  That would require an query on the City table to find it's related State.

How can I update the StateID field on the Activity table when the CityID combo box is updated?  At the same time I would like to refresh the form so that that State appears in the State combo box.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the following statement to the After Update event on the cboCity field:
Me!cboState = Dlookup("ParentStateID","City","ID = " & Me!cboCity.Column(0))